# create dynamic cell address with vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I have a column (column B in my case), with header named "case", with cells contains numbers.  I am writing a simple code to execute the tasks such that

1. for each cells in the column (do a for loop maybe), examine the previous 100 cells (frame)
2. when [average of 1st quarter < average of 2nd quarter < average of 3rd quarter] and [average of 4th quarter > average of 3rd quarter], I should add a "flag" to the cell on the right next to the cell hitting the criteria.

I would like to make the "frame" width and "quarter width" variable, and started coding for this.

```
sub check_pattern()

Dim boundary as integer
Set boundary = 5
Dim Framewidth as long
Set Framewidth = 100

Dim case as range
Set case = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(1).Find("case", lookat:=xlPart)
'declare column number of my data

Dim AR as integer, BR as integer, CR as integer, DR as integer, ER as integer
'declare row numbers of the boundaries of range of address, will be used in vba offset
AR = Round(Framewidth*(boundary - 1)/(boundary - 1))
BR = Round(Framewidth*(boundary - 2)/(boundary - 1))
CR = Round(Framewidth*(boundary - 3)/(boundary - 1))
DR = Round(Framewidth*(boundary - 4)/(boundary - 1))
ER = Round(Framewidth*(boundary - 5)/(boundary - 1))

Dim i as integer, LRow as long
Set LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(case))
'declare variables for the for loop
'For i = 2 to LRow
'[missing code]
'Next i

End sub
```

Now I'm difficult with the missing code part.  If the ranges involved were static, I would code like

```
if and Application.Average(Range("b2:b26")) < Application.Average(Range("b27:b51")) and Application.Average(Range("b27:b51")) < Application.Average(Range("b52:b76")) and Application.Average(Range("b52:b76")) > Application.Average(Range("b77:b101")) then range("C102").value = "Flag"
```

I would like to make this task looping through up til row number of 5XXXX (declared LRow) and the quarter width may be variable.  Can you fill up my missing part?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @John, your question is not very clear. My first question is How and where are you defining the **Quarters**? Because it will be the way to dynamically select your 1st to 4th Quarter and allow us to continue.

Comment: hi @TsiriniainaRakotonirina, let me try to clarify.

For Framewidth = 100, 100 rows should be examined.  For row index 2 to 101 (on column B), row 2 and 26 will be for the 1st quarter, row 27 to 51 will be for the 2nd quarter, row 52 to 76 will be for the 3rd quarter and row 77 to row 101 will be for the 4th quarter.  If criteria fulfilled, the "flag" will be added to range("C102").

Comment: In this example, 5 boundaries (A, B, C, D and E) were involved and I try to define the row indices (AR, BR, CR, DR and ER) for them with the formula in my code, for which the number of rows for each quarter may me modified if needed.